# Transfer from checking account?

Tags: c#, transfer

I'm Working on this program since yesterday but I do not know the cause of the problem. When, I run the program and enter the amount to transfer from Checking Account to Saving Account, the program subtracts the entered amount from the Checking account, but does not add to the Savings account.

How can I resolve this issue? Any help is appreciated.

```
public partial class Transfer : Window
{
    private string PIN;
    Accounts AccountsList = new Accounts();

    //constructor
    public Transfer(string pin, Accounts myAcounts)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AccountsList = myAcounts;
        PIN = pin;
    }

    //save to file method
    public void saveToFile()
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Acounts.txt"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < AccountsList.Count; i++)
            {
                var data = new List<string>
                {
                    AccountsList[i].ACCOUNTYPE.ToString()
                    ,AccountsList[i].PIN
                    ,AccountsList[i].ACCOUNTNUMBER
                    ,AccountsList[i].ACCOUNTBALANCE.ToString()
                };

                var account = String.Join(";", data);
                sw.WriteLine(account);
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string txtAmount = txtAmountInTransfer.Text;
            double amount = 0;

            bool AmountCorrect = double.TryParse(txtAmount, out amount);

            Account chequingAccount = new Account();
            Account savingAccount = new Account();

            //deposit from CHEQUING ACCOUNT to SAVING ACCOUNT
            {
                //validate user entries

                for (int i = 0; i < AccountsList.Count; i++)
                {
                    //withdraw from CHEQUING ACCOUNG
                    if (AccountsList[i].ACCOUNTYPE == 'C' && AccountsList[i].PIN == PIN)
                    {
                        if (rbChequing_to_Saving.IsChecked == true)
                        {
                            chequingAccount = AccountsList[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            savingAccount = AccountsList[i];
                        }

                        chequingAccount.ACCOUNTBALANCE -= amount;
                        AccountsList[i].ACCOUNTBALANCE += amount;


                        //saveToFile();
                        //break;

                    }
                    //if (AccountsList[i].ACCOUNTYPE == 'S')
                    //    savingAccount.ACCOUNTBALANCE += amount;

                    //saveToFile();
                }


            }


        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

With this statement, you are actually copying the reference not the value.

```
chequingAccount = AccountsList[i];
```

So both of these have the same reference.

```
chequingAccount.ACCOUNTBALANCE -= amount;
AccountsList[i].ACCOUNTBALANCE += amount;
```

you are subtracting x amount and then adding x amount back to it. You need to double check your logic.

Here is a good article about **value type vs Reference type**
http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type

Comment: Can You explain me a bit please im new with c#

Comment: @afgboy : Since Account (class) is a reference type, when you do `chequingAccount = AccountsList[i];`, you are copying reference of `AccountsList[i]` to `chequingAccount `. So if you change either of these, that will impact the value in other one. Read about **Value Types Vs Reference types**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suprised you say it is subtracting from checking.  My read of the code has it either adding or doing nothing to the checking.

the Reason, when you get to the +/- code you potentially set `chequingAccount = AccountsList[i]` based on a boolean from the GUI ... otherwise it is a newly created account that isn't in your AccountsList.

Thus your +/- code results in either:

```
AccountsList[i].ACCOUNTBALANCE -= amount;
AccountsList[i].ACCOUNTBALANCE += amount;
```

Or

```
(new Account()).ACCOUNTBALANCE -= amount;
AccountsList[i].ACCOUNTBALANCE += amount;
```

Somewhere you need to find the Savings Account.

I also notice that you don't check the back account number, only the PIN.  If two accounts have the same PIN, you might not subtract from the right account.